# Bad xml or android compatibility issue?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm developing my first app on android and I think my apply meets the requirements (using only dp or sp, etc...) needed to support multiple screens.

However, it seems I'm doing something wrong. Textviews gets overlapped at the bottom of the screen.

Now...did I wrote bad xml or do I need to add different layouts for each android version, to be sure to avoid this kind of problems?

First device spec (docomo ARROWS NX F-06E) 1080×1920 px, 16,777,216 colors
First device screenshot:

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/r8tp0oay3/Screenshot_2013_08_19_22_08_33.png]

Second device spec (LG L-07C Optimus) 480 x 800 px, 256K colors
Second device screenshot:
 [image: http://s22.postimg.org/xkqbne74h/i001.jpg]

Here is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_green"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:src="@drawable/sakai" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/random_field"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chronometer"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_bl"
android:text="@string/index"
android:textSize="20.5sp" />

<Chronometer android:id="@+id/chronometer"
 android:format="@string/chronometer_initial_format"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
 android:layout_weight="0.5"
 android:paddingBottom="30dip"
 android:paddingTop="30dip"
 />
 <Button
 android:layout_below="@id/image"
 android:id="@+id/askquestion"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/ask"
 style="@style/ButtonText" 
 android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states" 
 />
 <Button
  android:layout_below="@id/askquestion"
  android:id="@+id/answer1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/ask" 
  style="@style/ButtonText" 
  android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"/>
  <Button
  android:layout_below="@id/answer1"
  android:id="@+id/answer2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/ask" 
  style="@style/ButtonText" 
  android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"/>
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/answer3"
  android:layout_below="@id/answer2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/ask"
  style="@style/ButtonText" 
  android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states" />
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/answer4"
  android:layout_below="@id/answer3"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/ask" 
  style="@style/ButtonText" 
  android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"/>
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/score_field"
  android:layout_below="@id/answer4"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/score"
  android:textSize="24.5sp" 
  /> 
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/performance_field"
  android:layout_below="@id/score_field"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:textSize="24.5sp" 
  />

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:weightSum="4.0" >
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/difficult_textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/difficulty"
  android:textSize="24.5sp" 
  />
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWithButtons"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:weightSum="4.0" >

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/diff1"
  style="@style/ButtonText"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"
  android:text="@string/one" />
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/diff2"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_weight="1.0"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"
      android:text="@string/two" />
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/diff3"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_weight="1.0"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"
      android:text="@string/three" />
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/diff4"
      style="@style/ButtonText"
      android:layout_weight="1.0"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/btn_blue_states"
      android:text="@string/four" />

  </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you'll attach the screen shots here

Comment: Decrease text size or make several XML layout configurations based on screen's dimension

Comment: could you please provide information about drawables you are using? are you usinn 9patch images?

Comment: Do you mean in the comments? 
How it should appear http://i.stack.imgur.com/ueK8m.png
How it ishttp://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtrS.jpg

Comment: You are not telling us the _physical_ size of the screens. I guess the second one is noticeable smaller, so there is simply not enough space - a problem that no cross device GUI toolkit can solve yet.

Comment: I'm using 9patch images from this site http://www.dibbus.com/2011/03/9patch-images-in-android/

Comment: First device:  139mm×70mm×9.9mm
Second device: 122 x 64 x 10 mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple matter of aspect ratios:

- 1080x1920 is 16:9
- 480x800 is 5:3

So the higher resolution screen is a longer (taller) rectangle.  Your layout is designed well such that part of the layout will hang to the bottom and another part to the top, but you designed it with the taller screen in mind and so things are running together on the smaller screen.  You have one of two options:

1. Redesign the layout to fit properly on the shorter screen, in which case on the taller screen it will just stretch to show more extra space between the top and bottom sections.
2. Use resource qualifiers to create two different layouts for screens based on their height.  This level of effort only makes sense if you are trying to achieve a more pixel-perfect look regardless of the device's screen aspect.

Comment: I'll try redimensioning the font! Then I'll look up the resource qualifiers, just to be sure these things won't happen again! Thank you very much.